# Why isn't this Bash string substitution working?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to do a string substitution in bash to escape the dots in a version number to ultimately pass to grep. When I run

`echo ${3.9.1//./\\.}`

Expected output is `3\.9\.1`. I get a `bad substitution` error instead. I don't understand how this isn't correct.

Comment: `3.9.1` is not a valid parameter *name*. `bash` doesn't allow parameter-expansion operations on raw strings, only the results of parameter expansion. (`zsh`, on the other hand, does.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your string in a variable then you can use [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
s="3.9.1"
echo "${s//./\\.}"
```

Output:

```
3\.9\.1
```